# Pegar evento de tecla com VueJS

Tags: vue.js-2

Como posso pegar o evento de uma tecla com o Vue? já vi alguns exemplos no site como:

```
<input @keyup.enter="submit">
```

Porém o que eu gostaria é algum tipo de listener onde se o usuário apertar um tecla chamasse uma função, sem depender de button ou input.

Por exemplo, tenho um modal onde gostaria que ao usuário apertar a tecla ESC o modal fechasse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação do Vuejs2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html), há diversos modificadores de teclado, como você mostrou acima em seu `@keyup.enter`. No caso da tecla ESC, há o `.esc`, como, por exemplo, `@keyup.esc` ou `@keydown.esc`.

Para não ter que colocar isto dentro de um `input` ou `button`, pode não ser a melhor maneira, mas realizei uma demonstração abaixo que funcionará sempre que o ESC for pressionado (ou qualquer tecla, pois está configurado para `keyup`, porém há uma validação da tecla ESC, no caso *keyCode* 27):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.onEsc)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.onEsc)
  },
  methods: {
    onEsc(e) {
      if (!e) e = window.event
      let keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which
      if (keyCode == '27') {
        console.log('Esc foi pressionado')
        console.log(e.target)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Criar um evento que seja disparado ao apertar a tecla ESC</h1>
  <h2>Aperte a tecla ESC e verifique o console.</h2>
</div>
```